# Last working day in DB

Tags: mysql

I have data for all days of the week and i want to find data from most recent working day i.e `dayofweek != 1 and dayofweek != 7`

My clumsy WHERE with CASE is something along the lines of

```
WHERE CASE WHEN dayofweek(curdate()) = 1 THEN day(time) = date_sub(day(time), interval 2 day) 
    WHEN dayofweek(curdate()) = 7 THEN day(time) = date_sub(day(time), interval 1 day)  
    WHEN dayofweek(curdate()) != 7 AND dayofweek(curdate()) != 1 THEN day(time) = day(curdate())  ELSE 1 = 1  END
```

Comment: Show us what you have so far.

Comment: Another consideration; what if it's a holiday or any day where the business is closed?

Comment: @ChrisForrence not there yet, monday-friday would suffice for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code, `day(time) = date_sub(day(time), interval 2 day)` never matches, because `day(time)` ***never ever*** equals `day(time) - 1 day`.  That is the same as saying `x=x-1` in algebra... it simply can not be true.  I suspect you actually mean to do something like this:

```
WHERE CASE WHEN dayofweek(curdate()) = 1 THEN date(time) = date(date_sub(curdate(), interval 2 day)) 
...
...
... This part was left as an exercise for the asker.
```

The `date()` function removes the time part, so you can compare just the day.  `The date_sub()` function needs to subtract from `curdate()` to get the most recent workday.  In your code it was subtracting from the `DATETIME` stored in the table.

Comment: yea silly me, just a logic mistake!

Comment: Using `date()` instead of `day()` is super important too....  `day()` returns the day in the month, so it will seem to work for the first month, but in the second month of production it will start returning rows from the last workday of the current month, *and from the day with that number int he previous month.*